# How to evaluate javascript in Xamarin.Android/Monodroid and retrieve result?

Tags: javascript, android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin

For **Xamarin.iOS/Monotouch** it is simple to retrieve a string when evaluating **javascript**.

e.g.

```
string elementValue = browser.EvaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('Id').value");

if(elementValue != "")
{
   DoSomething();
}
```

Could anybody provide an example of how to do this for Xamarin. **Android/Monodroid** using loadURL(javascript:)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Android KitKat EvaluateJavascript in Xamarin.Android/Monodroid and retrieve result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114668/how-to-use-android-kitkat-evaluatejavascript-in-xamarin-android-monodroid-and-re)